# is it possible to select one checkbox and deselect the other checkbox? (VBA required)

Tags: vba, excel, checkbox

I have 2 checkboxes, what i want to do is when i select one, the other 1 will be deselected, which means user will not have the ability to select it the other checkbox. I was wondering if it is possible to do so?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Yes it is possible. But why not use an option button instead?

Anyways to answer your query.

```
Private Sub CheckBox1_Click()
    If CheckBox1.Value = True Then
        CheckBox2.Value = False
        CheckBox2.Enabled = False
    Else
        CheckBox2.Enabled = True
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub CheckBox2_Click()
    If CheckBox2.Value = True Then
        CheckBox1.Value = False
        CheckBox1.Enabled = False
    Else
        CheckBox1.Enabled = True
    End If
End Sub
```

**FOLLOWUP**

> > > Thanks for the fast update! what is the difference between a checkbox and option button? I thought they do the same thing? – user1204868 48 secs ago

Excel VBA **Option Buttons** (*Also known as radio buttons*) are the same as **Check Boxes** except that **Option Buttons** are dependent on each other while **Check Boxes** are not. When you check one **Option Button** the other **Option Button** will automatically get unchecked.

See the snapshot below on how they look :)

Would recommend seeing the Excel's inbuilt VBA help for more details ;)

**SNAPSHOT:**

[image]

HTH

Sid

Comment: Thanks for the fast update! what is the difference between a checkbox and option button? I thought they do the same thing?

Comment: ok.. but please do not remove the answers for the checkbox.. I think it will benefit others too! :)

Comment: Hi thanks! I will have a look at how the option button works! For now, the deselecting is good enough!

Comment: +1 dependent checkboxes should really be option buttons instead.

Comment: Checkboxes may be need if one box over rules two other boxes, yet the other two boxes can be checked at the same time.

Answer (score 0):

I also had this problem because I didn't want to use option buttons on my form, so I have written some code for this case and it works! But there maybe a more appropriate way of writing code for this matter. Do as the following list:

(For example you have four checkboxes in your form, there is no difference in the number of them.)

1- Name your userform (which the checkboxes are on) with an appropriate name in it's properties window. The name property is the first in the properties window (in the alphabetic tab). This is for so that we can easier approach an call the userform when where writing the necessary code using the intelisense list.

For example: userform1

2- Name your checkboxes with an appropriate name in their properties window. The name property is the first in the properties window (in the alphabetic tab). This is for so that we can easier approach an call the checkboxes when where writing the necessary code using the intelisense list.

For example: chkbox1, chkbox2, chkbox3 and chkbox4

3- Click on one of the checkboxes in the userform (in the vb editor) and you see that the click event has been generated. Click the right hand side drop down list and choose the "after updating" event. Erase the click event sub routine of that checkbox in order to tidy up the vb editor.

4- In between this subroutine, for example:

```
Private Sub Chkbox1_AfterUpdate()


End Sub
```

We will write such code:

```
Private Sub Chkbox1_AfterUpdate()

      userform1.Chkbox2.Value = False
      userform1.Chkbox3.Value = False
      userform1.Chkbox4.Value = False

End Sub
```

Note 1: As you can see in this code, when the user clicks chkbox1, an afterupdate happens in which the value of all the chkboxes (except chkbox1) gets called and their values get turned into false.

Note 2: As you can see, we have to write such for the other checkboxes' afterupdate events, but be careful to write the code only for the other checkboxes, for example if your writing code for chkbox1, then chxbox1 shouldn't be written it's code below it, this rule is for all the other checkboxes respectedly. If you don't write the code based on this rule, your code wont work then.

5- Write the proper code for the other 3 or etc checkboxes' afterevent respectedly. and the code is ready to work.

If you want to see an overall view of the necessary code (just in case), for 4 checkboxes on 1 userform, it should look like this:

```
Private Sub Chkbox1_AfterUpdate()

      userform1.Chkbox2.Value = False
      userform1.Chkbox3.Value = False
      userform1.Chkbox4.Value = False

End Sub

Private Sub Chkbox2_AfterUpdate()

      userform1.Chkbox1.Value = False
      userform1.Chkbox3.Value = False
      userform1.Chkbox4.Value = False

End Sub

Private Sub Chkbox3_AfterUpdate()

      userform1.Chkbox1.Value = False
      userform1.Chkbox2.Value = False
      userform1.Chkbox4.Value = False

End Sub

Private Sub Chkbox4_AfterUpdate()

      userform1.Chkbox1.Value = False
      userform1.Chkbox2.Value = False
      userform1.Chkbox3.Value = False

End Sub
```

Note 3: The names you use for the userform and the checkboxes are up to you and there is no restriction. You can use Hungarian notations for having more proper names.

Answer (score -1):

```
Private Sub CheckBox1_Click()

If CheckBox2.Enabled = True Then
    CheckBox2.Enabled = False
    Else
    CheckBox2.Enabled = True

    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: This does not seem to be the complete answer to the question. You are only handling the case in which only the first checkbox is clicked.

Comment: While this code snippet may be the solution, [including an explanation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-%E2%80%8C%E2%80%8Bcode-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.